# Counting the number of an element in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

So for an assignment in my class, we have a lab where we have to write code that will do three things:

1. generate an array of 50 random numbers from 0-9.
2. Return how many 8's appear in the array.
3. Return the number of runs in the array.

We were given a .java file to start out with that is this:

```
package ArrayOfInts;
public class ArrayOfInts {
  private int [] intArray;
  private int eights;
  private int runs;

  //Sets intArray to the parameter and initializes all other variables
  public ArrayOfInts(int [] x){


  }

  //Returns how many 8's are in the array.
  public int findTheEights(){

    return eights;
  }

  //Returns the number of runs in the array.
  public int countTheRuns(){      




    return runs;
  }
}
```

The code I've written so far is this:

```
package ArrayOfInts;
public class ArrayOfIntsTester {
  public static void main(String [] args){
    int [] testArray = new int [50];
    for(int i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++){
      int x = (int)(Math.random()*9);
      testArray[i]= x;
      System.out.print(x + ", ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    ArrayOfInts test = new ArrayOfInts(testArray);
    System.out.println(test.findTheEights());
    System.out.println(test.countTheRuns());

  }
}
```

I honestly have no idea where to start with this.  Help??  The code I've written generates the correct type of array, but I don't know how to count what I need to count for it.

Comment: @jhamon He's referring `private int runs;`

Comment: Can you elaborate on `runs`? Do you mean if the same number appears consecutive times, or if you have a sequence of, say, 7-8-9?

Comment: @ Maroun Maroun I think this `runs`is like his `eights` and is just here to store the result of his function (i.e. is probably useless as those  2 variables are never used).

Comment: Think about it as though you were going to do it by hand. Look at every element (for loop), compare each element to 8 (== operator), if it is 8, increment your counter for number of instances of 8 in the array (++ operator). You should elaborate further one what runs means in your program.

Comment: Can you clarify your question, what does runs means? People are guessing here rather than answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
//To count number of eights, iterate through array with a counter and increment it when we see an 8
public ArrayOfInts(int [] x){
eights = 0; //reset our count
    for (int currentInt : intArray)
    {
        if (currentInt == 8)
            eights++;
    }
//Process runs here
}
```

Comment: I think the intention is for the calculation to be done in the constructor. At least based on the comments and the fact that `eights` is a field.

Answer (score 0):

For the eights: iterate over the array and do `eights++` everytime you find an eight.

```
if (testArray[i] == 8){
    eights++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To count the number of eight just use another variable which is initialized to 0 , like this :-

```
int c=0;
for (i=0;i<testArray.length;i++)
{
 if (testArray[i] == 8)
  {
   c++;
  }
}
```

Now your c has the number of 8's present in your array you cant print its value.

--> If that's what you are trying to ask

Comment: Your `for` loop really should not be set to a static number for the iterations. `50` should be `testArray.length`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudo code to help you count the eights:

```
numberOfEights = 0;
for each element in testArray{
    if (element equals 8) {
        numberOfEights  = nnumberOfEight + 1
    } else {
        nothing to do
    }
}
return numberOfEights
```

Try to turn this to java code.

For the other part, i don't understand what is your `runs`.

Answer (score 0):

first initialize the array in `constructor`

```
  public ArrayOfInts(int [] x){
      intArray=x;
  }
```

initialize the eights to 0

```
 private int eights=0;
```

then update your count method

```
  public int findTheEights(){      
    for(int current:intArray)
    {
       if(current==8){ eights++;}
    }
    return eights;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you could do it like the following example.

Counting of eights can be done directly at the initializaion of the array.

And if I understand you right, you'd like to count the instances of the object with the countTheRuns(). That can be done with a class variable.

If you'd like to play with the code, you'll find it here at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/zx3h2wd2/).

```js
/*So for an assignment in my class, we have a lab where we have to write code that will do three things:

    generate an array of 50 random numbers from 0-9.
    Return how many 8's appear in the array.
    Return the number of runs in the array.
*/
(function() {
    
    var MAX_RANDOM = 50;
    var NUM_RANGE = 9; // 0 to 9
    
    function ArrayOfInts() {
        this.eights = 0;
        this.numbers = [];
        this.init();
        // class variabe run_counter
        ArrayOfInts.run_counter = (ArrayOfInts.run_counter || 0) +1;
        
        this.getNumbers = function() {
            return this.numbers;
        };
        
        this.getEights = function() {
            return this.eights;
        };
    }

    ArrayOfInts.prototype.init = function() {
        for (var i=0; i< MAX_RANDOM; i++) {
            var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*(NUM_RANGE+1));
            this.numbers.push(randNum);
            if (randNum == 8) this.eights++;
        }
    };
    
    // demo usage code ---------------------
    var array = new ArrayOfInts();
    var array2 = new ArrayOfInts();
    
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = array.getNumbers();
    console.log(array.getNumbers());
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += '<br/>The array has the following no. of eights: ' + array.getEights(); 
    
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += '<br/>The number generation ran ' + ArrayOfInts.run_counter + ' times.';
    
})();
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, thought there was also a Javascript tag. Anyway, the OOP stuff also works in Java, just with different syntax.